# JQuery datepicker not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I recently migrated from JQuery 1.2 to JQuery 1.3. However, the DatePicker UI is giving me a problem. I have a text field within a JQuery dialog. A datepicker is attached to this field. When I click on the field the datepicker pops up but behind the dialog box, which blocks out almost the entire DatePicker. Also, the DatePicker does not display next to the text field but way below it. Is there anything I can do to position the datepicker properly?

EDIT: Here is my declaration of the datepicker:

```
$("#date").datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'DD, d MM yy',
        minDate: 0,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: "Choose a date",
        buttonImage: '/images/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        hideIfNoPrevNext: true
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Draco, some source could would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, my bad...added the source code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please update to the latest JQuery Build. Afaik this has been a bug in a recent build.

Comment: I solved the problem by setting the z-index to 99999, but I think I will rather update to the latest build as you said just to be safe.